# for loop in hash table printing only last value

Tags: perl

Please advice.

```
for my $record (@item) {
    for my $int (@$record){
       #       DEBUG( "DEBUG:: $record and $int");
             my %data = ( $record , $int );
                }
        }
}
```

Record is like

```
abc ,china
abc ,japan
abc , italy
abc , singapore

print Dumper %data;
output :
abc , singapore
```

Now the issues is when I dump the output it shows me last record entry in hash table.May be because of unique key.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: `%data` is a hash. If you have all times the key 'abc' the hash only stores the last added value!

Comment: I am able to get correct variable values from @item array because i get correct output from debug $record and $int as shown in question....

Comment: mpapec / Jens is there any way to append data in array or hash because in below part of the script i am checking if the value exists then remove from hash/array.

Comment: A hash must contain unique keys. Modify your program according to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are recreating the hash in each iteration of the loop. The correct way would be

   ```
   my %data;
   for my $record (@item) {
       for my $int (@$record){
           $data{$record} = $int;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Hash keys must be unique. It's not possible to have a hash like

   ```
   ( abc => 'china',
     abc => 'japan' )
   ```

   You can use a hash of arrays, though. Just assign to it with

   ```
   push @{ $data{$record} }, $int;
   ```

   It will create the following structure:

   ```
   ( abc => [ 'china', 'japan', 'italy', 'singapore' ] )
   ```